# Stripe Payment Method Not Being Saved - IOS & Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments, payment

I'm trying to save a credit card for a stripe customer, however, when I implement the test card given by stripe (42424242...) I get the message: "Your Card Was Declined".

This is what I have tried to solve the issue:

1. Made sure to have my test keys instead of live ones
2. Tried with international credit cards (as I'm located in Mexico)
3. Made sure that I was getting the ephemeral key
4. Tried Live with a real credit card and I still got the message "Your Card was Declined" - even if I'm not asking to charge anything but input the credit card

Note: The tutorial I'm following used a method called .createCardSources = true , however, I believe that's depreciated.

This is my function:

```
func setupStripeConfig() {
        //2.) Create stripe payment configuration
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared()
        
        #warning(".createCard sources not appearing")
//        config.createCardSources --> Doesn't show
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .none
        
        
        //1.)we need that customer context found in Stripe Api
        //this will invoke the cloud function, generate the ephemeral key, pass it back and this customer context class will prefetch the stripe customer's information from it's stripe object (say saved credit cards)
        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
        
        //3.)now we need to create stripe payment context
        paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .default())
        
        //4.) Set payment context, payment amount
        paymentContext.paymentAmount = self.stripeTotal!
        
        //5.)Set payment context & delegate
        paymentContext.delegate = self
        paymentContext.hostViewController = self
        
    }
```

I am receiving the ephemeral key, so that shouldn't be the issue, however I'll put the code here as well:

```
import Foundation
import Stripe
import FirebaseFunctions

let StripeApi = _StripeApi()


class _StripeApi: NSObject, STPEphemeralKeyProvider {
    
    
    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        
        //data object
        let data = [
            "stripe_version": apiVersion,
            "customer_id": UserService.user.stripeId
        ]
        
        print("API VERSION: \(apiVersion)")
        print("CUSTOMER ID: \(UserService.user.stripeId)")
        
        //This will invoke our cloud function
        //you need to create a data object and then pass it to this function
        Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createEphemeralKey").call(data) { (result, error) in
            //ephemeral key should be found in result
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in StripeApi.swift \(error)")
                //if we have an error we will need to pass completion (nil for json) and error for error
                completion(nil,error)
                return
            }
            guard let key = result?.data as? [String: Any] else {
                completion(nil,nil)
                return
            }
            
            //if we do get the key, we'll pass it over in completion and put nil for error
            completion(key,nil)
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: "Your Card Was Declined" is the very straightforward reason. You can't use whatever card you are attempting to use. Stripe provides test cards here: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Comment: I used those test cards. I used the 42424242

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out to Stripe via https://support.stripe.com/email then as they can dig into exactly what your requests are doing and why you're seeing that error.

Comment: But doesn't this have something to do with my code?

Comment: Based on the error you're describing, it's not likely. If you can find a longer stack trace, do you know where that error is originating?

Comment: @taintedzodiac well I'm able to get the ephemeral key and display and able to display pushPaymentOptionsViewController() the stripe default one, so I'm assuming that the issue is with the STPPaymentContext that I'm creating, step 3.) in my setupStripeConfig function.